# How to populate a dataframe column based on a lookup of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a sample dataframe using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Dict

data: Dict = {'Child': ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta'],
              'Age': [20, 30, 40, 50],
              'Parent': ['Delta', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

The output of the above code snippet is as follows:

```
     Child  Age   Parent
0    Alpha   20    Delta
1    Bravo   30    Delta
2  Charlie   40     Echo
3    Delta   50  Foxtrot
```

I would like to add another column called 'Parent Age' that looks at the Child column to see if Parent is in it and if so, it fetches the corresponding Age from the Age column. If the Parent is not in the Child Column, the Parent Age column value should be populated by doing an extra function call to get_parent_age(name).

Here is the sample output that I am looking for:

```
     Child  Age   Parent  Parent Age
0    Alpha   20    Delta  50
1    Bravo   30    Delta  50
2  Charlie   40     Echo  get_parent_age(Echo)
3    Delta   50  Foxtrot  get_parent_age(Foxtrot)
```

My real dataset has many more rows, but hopefully you get the gist. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If there are 1 million names to be fetched then it'll be a really inefficient way. Rather if parent's name in another dataframe, just apply a join based on the unique column and fetch all at once in a new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df['Parent_age'] = df.Parent.map(dict(df[['Child' , 'Age']].values))

# when Parent is not in Child column, then apply get_parent_age
cond = df['Parent_age'].isnull()
df.loc[cond, 'Parent_age'] = df.loc[cond, 'Parent'].map(get_parent_age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df["Parent Age"]= df["Parent"].apply( lambda x: df[df["Child"]==x]["Age"])
    x=np.where(df['Parent Age'].isna()) # this returns the a 2D array of indices where the value is None, NaN
    arr = np.array(x).reshape(-1) # Creating a 1D array
    for i in arr:
        df.at[i,"Parent Age"] = get_parent_age(df.at[i, "Parent"]) #getting the age for each parent whose age was not there
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "other columns" have an index or the source is a `Series` the following will work:

```
df['parent_age'] = df.Parent.map(parent_age_series.to_dict())
```